# Importing a file from Excel 2010 to visual studio SQL Server

Tags: sql, database, excel

I have some data that in excel file (cvs file), how can I import those data to the sql database for the website?

ps: I am using vs2013, excel 2013.

also, I am really a beginner, please show all the detail for the problem.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using Import Wizard in Sql Server Management Studioo.
Right click on the database and go to Tasks > Import Data .
In Choose Data Source dialog Box , Select Excel option from drop down list.

[Follow steps here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3580216/SQL-Server-2005-Import--Export-Wizard.htm)